# Owncloud on the raspberry pi

Tags: server, setup, owncloud

I am trying to install owncloud on the raspberry and I found this link:

http://blog.petrockblock.com/2012/08/15/your-own-cloud-server-with-owncloud-on-the-raspberry-pi/

I followed every step but when I get to the sudo `./owncloudpie_setup.sh` part, I get a different setup screen. (I am also new to Owncloud) See my Attachement. This is what it looks like:
[image]
 When I try to change server url, I get to:

Please enter the url of your Owncloud server:

```
lqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
x16
```

And the only thing I can change is `16` not even the `x`

How do I setup my Owncloud server as I want in this screen? And why is the url so weird?

Any one can explain how to set it up the right way from this menu?

Comment: If you'd like to ask a new question, feel free.  If you'd like to rework the question, you can make edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks kind of like there's some locale<sup>1</sup> or similar issue.  The `q`'s are probably supposed to be horizontal lines, the `x`'s vertical, and the `j`'s, `m`s and `k`s and `l`s four styles of corner symbol.

The potential for problems like these may be compounded if you are accessing the system remotely, because of some mismatch in encoding.  Everything should still work, it just looks ugly.

<sup>1</sup> Locale is partially about [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).  Note that "locales" are not necessarily about a human language, and may instead derive from various formats, some of which relate to the decades long evolution of terminal types, etc.

Comment: I did install via ssh...

Comment: Can you delete your comment so I can delete my question?

Comment: The reason I don't want to do that is that if somebody else has this problem in the future they may find this and bring more attention/insight/information.  If you were using ssh, obviously my answer was wrong, of course, so I've changed it to guess number 2.  Again, the goal is not just to help you, but to leave a solution for others in the future.

Comment: ok thanks. Indeed everything did work although I have a different error at a different part. Nothing really to do with this but thanks anyway.

Comment: If you do figure it out, you can post your own answer and tick that. ;)

Comment: My solution is kind of a bad solution which wont really help anyone, I reinstalled and I could choose the server url in the installation, but your help was way more usefull man. You explained that the weird random letters aren't a problem.

Comment: Can you also help me with this problem I am getting? http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11795/runtime-noapps-true-no-apps-yet-require-once-lib-base-php-och

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing owncloud using apt-get... this gives you the ability to update to a newer version whenever you want.
A good manual how to do it that way: [software.opensuse.org setup manual](http://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv:ownCloud:community&package=owncloud)

Comment: The OP did not specify to work on a *bian, so it's still possible that `apt-get` is not an option.

Comment: The link with the setup manual he posted does also use apt-get, so I assume it is a *bian system...

Comment: Fair enough ;) (I did not follow the links)